# Fatal error: Class 'Database' not found

Tags: php, database, class, object, mysqli

I've searched, and I can't seem to find a solution to my problem.

Whenever I try to initiate a new object `$con = new Database();`, I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Database' not found in /customers/c/6/f/rowweb.dk/httpd.www/toolkit/e/includes/php/db/connect.php on line 3
```

I've troubleshooted a bit, and it's connecting just fine to my database. I'm even trying to initiate the object from within the same file as my Database class.

Here's my db connect:

```
$con = new Database();

class Database extends mysqli {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct('host', 'username', 'pass', 'database');
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            throw new Exception(mysqli_connect_error(),   
            mysqli_connect_errno());
        } 
    } 
}
```

Anyone who knows what might be the problem?

Comment: Seems like you dont include the class into connect.php...

Comment: Have you included the file that contains your class? Check if it is included properly and is instantiable with `class_exists()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP, classes have to be declared before they can be instantiated.

From http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php:

> **new**
>
> To create an instance of a class, the new keyword must be used. An object will always be created unless the object has a constructor defined that throws an exception on error. ***Classes should be defined before instantiation (and in some cases this is a requirement).***

Since your instantiation and class declaration occur in the same file, and your error occurred at line 3, this is very likely your problem.

Comment: Damn, of course. Stupid mistake, thanks for pointing it out! :)

Answer (score 1):

**Unless you have some other code that is not shown here**, your problem is that you have not included the file which defines the Database object.

There are a couple of ways to accomplish this, either by using `include/include_once` or `require/require_once`, or by using an autoloader.

**Include & Require**

This method of inclusion will, in effect, join the included file to the current file. For example, if you have a file called `a.php` like this:

```
$varA = 'I am A!';
```

and a file called `b.php` like this:

```
include('a.php');
echo $varA;
```

...you can write code in `b.php` *as though the code in a.php were in the same file*. The alternative to `include`, `require`, works exactly the same, with one important difference. If a file that is `include`'d cannot be found, a warning will be issued. If a file that is `require`'d cannot be found, it will be a fatal error.

Both flavors have a `*_once` variation. Without it, the file is appended each time, whereas `include_once` will only append the code the first time it is called on a given file.

**Autoloader**

There are two ways to add an autoloader. An autoloader is a "helper" that guides your script to the correct location of a file. This code is executed whenever you attempt to create a new class using the `new` keyword, or in certain other circumstances.

One method of autoloading uses the magic function [__autoload](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.autoload.php). As a general rule, don't use this. The alternative is `spl_autoload_register`[[docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php)], which registers a given function as a "helper". Unless you have a specific reason not to use this approach, you should.

Here is a simple example, right from the documentation:

```
function my_autoloader($class) {
    include 'classes/' . $class . '.class.php';
}
spl_autoload_register('my_autoloader');
```

**Documentation**

- `include` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php
- `require` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php
- Autoloading - http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Comment: But isn't that what I'm doing here: `$con = new Database();`? All this is in my connection-file which is `require_once ('path')` on index, and is in the right path, since it has no problem connecting to my database.

Comment: @JensAagren Without seeing that code, how could I possibly address it!? :) Why don't you post all the relevant code in your question, and I'll take another look. To answer your question, `$con = new Database();` is not the same as including the appropriate file, no. Not without an autoloader!

Comment: Well, it is in the block of code in my original post. Yes, I forgot to add it in the first post, but it was edited somewhat 10 seconds later.

Comment: There's no code in your question that shows where you require or include the database class file. Anyway...